# How can I recognize a special delimiter string when reading from a file of strings?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, fileinputstream, datainputstream

I want to read strings from a file. When a certain string (`><`) is found, I want to start reading integers instead, and convert them to binary strings.

My program is reading the strings in and saving them in an `ArrayList` successfully, but 
it does not recognise the `><` symbol and therefore the reading of the binary strings is not successful.

The Code

---

```
try {
    FileInputStream fstream = new FileInputStream(fc.getSelectedFile().getPath());
    // Get the object of DataInputStream
    DataInputStream ino = new DataInputStream(fstream);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(ino));
    String ln;
    String str, next;
    int line, c =0;

    while ((ln = br.readLine()) != null) {
        character = ln;
        System.out.println(character);
        iname.add(ln); // arraylist that holds the strings
        if (iname.get(c).equals("><")) {
            break; // break and moves
            // on with the following while loop to start reading binary strings instead.

        }
        c++;
    }

    String s = "";
    // System.out.println("SEQUENCE of bytes");

    while ((line = ino.read()) != -1) {
        String temp = Integer.toString(line, 2);
        arrayl.add(temp);
        System.out.println("telise? oxii");
        System.out.println(line);
    }

    ino.close();

} catch (Exception exc) { }
```

The file I'm trying to read is for example:

```
 T 
 E 
 a
 v 
 X 
 L 
 A 
 . 
 x 
 "><" 
 sequence of bytes.
```

Where the last part is saved as bytes and in the textfile appears like that. no worries this bit works. all the strings are saved in a new line.

Comment: Is the "><" going to be in a line by itself? Because otherwise what you've written is not going to work. Are there maybe any additional characters in that line (spaces, etc.)?

Comment: Can you give an example of the format you are trying to read?

Comment: @Christina yes the "><" its in a line by itself. nothing else is written in that line.

Comment: Always read the spec of the methods you are using.  [`read()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#read()) doesn't do what you expect it to do.  Don't assume what it does just based on the return type.

Comment: The thing is that only the first loop is actually done. and reads all the strings and the binaries as strings too

Answer (score 0):

Could you not do something like:

```
while ((ln = br.readLine()) != null){
            character=ln;
            System.out.println(character);

            //
            // Look for magic characters >< and stop reading if found
            //

            if (character.indexOf("><") >= 0) {
               break;
            }

            iname.add(ln);
    }
```

This would work if you didn't want to add the magic symbol to your ArrayList. Your code sample is incomplete - if you're still having trouble you'd need to post the whole class.

Comment: you meant >= 0... < 0 will break at every line except the one he needs.

Comment: Oops. You're right. Thanks for pointing that out, it's fixed.

Answer (score 0):

> < is two characters and iname.get(c) is only one character.

What u should do is test if ln equals > and then another test if the next character equals < . If both test pass then break out of the loop.

you will have to becarefull

Answer (score 0):

Use a [Scanner](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html). It allows you to specify a delimiter, and has methods for reading input tokens as String or int.